# Generate a few Promises without responding to all of them?

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an action which creates a new Promise and return a resolve:

```
actions: {
    myAction(context, data) {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             this.$http("/api/something").then(response => {
                resolve(response);
            }, error => {
                 reject(error);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Now, I have two components calling this action (generating two new Promises), but only the second function needs to do another action after the resolve arrives.

```
firstCall: function() {
     this.$store.dispatch("myAction");
}

secondCall: function() {
     this.$store.dispatch("myAction").then(response => {
         //Do something after receiving new data
     }, error => {
         console.error("Error")
     })
}
```

Is this a mistake/bad practice to generate a Promise without responding to all of its resolves?

Comment: If you don't need to do anything then you don't need to do anything. That's not wrong.

Comment: You don't need to wrap in an extra `new Promise`, just return the result of `this.$http`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a mistake/bad practice to generate a Promise without responding to all of its resolves?

It's fine not to necessarily process resolutions, but not processing *rejections* is generally poor practice (and in fact, now generates warnings from up-to-date browsers; and NodeJS will soon be updated [unless it already has been] to terminate its process on an unhandled rejection).

So you want to be sure you `catch` any errors:

```
firstCall: function() {
    this.$store.dispatch("myAction")
        .catch(error => /* something here */);
}
```

(`secondCall` is already doing that, with the second argument to `then`.)

---

Unrelated, but that code exhibits the promise-creation-antipattern. You don't need a new promise, you already have one. Just:

```
actions: {
    myAction(context, data) {
         return this.$http("/api/something");
    }
}
```

That does **exactly** what your code does, but more efficiently. Even if you're doing something in those `then` handlers that you've removed for the purposes of the question, since `then` returns a new promise, you wouldn't need `new Promise`.